# Why garbage collection is running too often in Windows 10 UWP app?

Tags: c#, windows, garbage-collection, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

Why garbage collection is blocking UI thread in Windows 10 UWP? (May not. But performance diagnostics tool said that garbage collector is running in UI Thread)
[image: blocking UI thread]
Also app is not responding if garbage collection is running. 
In Windows Phone 8.1 it works fine and doesn't call garbage collection so often.
[image: windows 10 UWP garbage collection]

**update:**
Updated result from Diagnostics tool:
[image]

**update 2**
I need to get large objects from external API(1000-2000 objects per month for the last 2 years). API returns data in json format. I'm using Newtonsoft.Json for the deserializing objects. So it's desired behavior to get 1-2 mb of temporary data per request from API. I have analyzed PerfView logs from device using FieldMedic and found that deserialization of collection is most expensive operation. The same results for the Windows Phone 8.1. The big difference only in JITStats number of methods 6,734 in Windows 10 versus 421 in WP 8.1
[image]

The same app for the Windows Phone 8.1 doesn't block UI thread. 
[image]
The question is "why it's required so much resources from garbage collection in Windows 10 UWP?".

**update 3**
Demo project demonstrates the difference. In WP8.1 UI thread cannot be blocked by json serialization/deserialization. In Windows 10 UI thread is blocked by GC.

```
private void StartButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {        
        Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            var storageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///trips.json"));
            var content = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(storageFile);
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                var trips = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Trip>>(content);                    
            }
        });
    }
```

link to the demo project:
[gc_test](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=2EE525DCF983EBC7!655&authkey=!AF66Addiv-JLk3c&ithint=file%2Czip)

Comment: Generally, you cannot control when Garbage collector is running. It cannot run on UI thread. Based on the results, it is the networking operations which take most of your time

Comment: Could you check updates? And are you still sure that garbage collector cannot in UI thread? And why app is not responding in that case? no other activities here.

Comment: @vadiblis: The GC usually runs in a separate thread, but may need to stop all other threads to do its work, so you'll still see it as a pause.

Comment: Thanks @Joey. How can I investigate the exact reason of this long pause (10s)? In WP 8.1 it takes 2 ms.

Comment: You allocate too much at once that you don't need for long, apparently. I'm not sure how well it works with UWP applications, but for normal .NET applications I used [PerfView](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567) which can tell you a lot about the runtime behaviour of the application, including telling you when and how many objects of certain types you allocate.

Comment: capture a trace via FiledMedic App on your phone, connect the phone to your PC, copy the genreated files to your PC and analyse the ETL with PerfView: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-125-PerfView-Part-8

Comment: Thanks @magicandre1981. I have analyzed logs with PerfView and it seems that DeserializeObject from Newtonsoft.Json the most expensive operation.

Comment: I have prepared demo project, so you can see the difference between WP8.1 and Windows 10 UWP. https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=2EE525DCF983EBC7!655&authkey=!AF66Addiv-JLk3c&ithint=file%2czip

Comment: report it to the devs: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues